# Joining paths in CMake

Tags: cmake

I am trying to join two paths together:

```
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/../${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/inkscape")
```

but a string concatenation does not really do it when `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` contains an absolute path.

Is there a CMake function that takes multiple path arguments and joins relative paths right of the rightmost absolute path to the absolute path, like Python’s [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) does?

Examples from Python interpreter showing desired behaviour:

```
>>> from os.path import join
>>> join("/foo/bar", "/baz/qux")
'/baz/qux'
>>> join("foo/bar", "/baz/qux")
'/baz/qux'
>>> join("/foo/bar", "./baz/qux")
'/foo/bar/./baz/qux'
>>> join("/foo/bar", "../baz/qux")
'/foo/bar/../baz/qux'
>>> join("./foo/bar", "baz/qux")
'./foo/bar/baz/qux'
```

I need to handle both the cases where the prefix is absolute (e.g. `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`), and where it is relative (e.g. `$ORIGIN/..` or `${prefix}` often needed for `pkg-config` files). And orthogonally, I need to handle both Linux distributions that use relative `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR`, and those that use an absolute one.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is absolute, and so is `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` (most of the time). Why not just `${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/foo`? See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html .

Comment: Please provide an example of what you tried (i.e. the resultant directory path) **and** an example of the desired directory path.

Comment: @Justin I do not think `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` is absolute most of the time. The documentation you linked mentions “`lib` or `lib64` or `lib/<multiarch-tuple>` on Debian” as an example. And quite a few of the software projects I encountered as a distribution package maintainer assumes that the `CMAKE_INSTALL_xxx` not suffixed by `_FULL` are relative.

Comment: @squareskittles I am trying to do is [package](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/50286) an alpha version of Inkscape but they [switched](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/commit/8294023227f1ec5d71956ee5e6cd46a4f03b2b93#9a2aa4db38d3115ed60da621e012c0efc0172aae_59_60) precisely to the style in the OP, assuming the `LIBDIR` is relative, while Nix uses absolute `LIBDIR`, resulting in `$ORIGIN/..//nix/store/7gifw2g1qkjvqf7bdkhxxhxzy49980zs-inkscape-1.0-alpha2/lib/inkscape`. I want to propose an upstream patch that handles both variants.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that CMake does not have a simple function for joining two paths, while Meson [has it from get go](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#join_paths) and even [introduced a `/` operator](https://mesonbuild.com/Release-notes-for-0-49-0.html#joining-paths-with-) to make the operation more convenient.

Comment: @squareskittles I added some examples of Python’s `os.path.join` function.

Comment: @JanTojnar Do you want something in CMake that will support *each* of those five cases?

Comment: @squareskittles they are just four cases, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57382992/joining-paths-in-cmake/57383772#comment101252037_57383772. And yes, I need to support all four of them.

Comment: @JanTojnar Indeed, it looks like it can often be relative. Hmm. For your case, isn't what you want `CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR`? "If the value is not already an absolute path, an absolute path is constructed typically by prepending the value of the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable. However, there are some special cases as documented below."

Comment: @Justin That would work for that specific case but not for other combinations. I now changed the example to the actual code in Inkscape to make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**September 2020:** `cmake_path` command has just been merged: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/5158

---

I have sent an example implementation to the [upstream issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19568#note_704230). It supports multiple arguments like the Python’s `os.path.join` and works on Linux at least:

```
# Modelled after Python’s os.path.join
# https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.join
# Windows not supported
function(join_paths joined_path first_path_segment)
    set(temp_path "${first_path_segment}")
    foreach(current_segment IN LISTS ARGN)
        if(NOT ("${current_segment}" STREQUAL ""))
            if(IS_ABSOLUTE "${current_segment}")
                set(temp_path "${current_segment}")
            else()
                set(temp_path "${temp_path}/${current_segment}")
            endif()
        endif()
    endforeach()
    set(${joined_path} "${temp_path}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

It would still be nice if CMake supported such essential functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: UPDATED BASED ON OP FEEDBACK**

Nothing in CMake supports exactly what you want out of the box. However, you can easily create your own [`if`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html) statements (using `IS_ABSOLUTE`) for the four scenarios you describe:

```
if(IS_ABSOLUTE ${PREFIX_DIR})
    if(IS_ABSOLUTE ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
        # Both absolute.
        set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PKGLIBDIR ....)
    else()
        # Prefix is absolute, but LIBDIR is relative.
        set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PKGLIBDIR ....)
    endif()
else()
    if(IS_ABSOLUTE ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
        # Prefix is relative, but LIBDIR is absolute.
        set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PKGLIBDIR ....)
    else()
        # Both are relative.
        set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PKGLIBDIR ....)
    endif()
endif()
```

This can be generalized and made into a [`function`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html), called `directory_join()` or something, and could be used throughout your CMake files wherever you need it.

---

Assuming I'm interpreting your question correctly, you **can** accomplish a `join` mechanism with CMake. If you have some absolute path and some relative path(s) you want to join, the [`get_filename_component()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_filename_component.html) command can help. Here's a general example:

```
set(ABS_PATH "C:/the/absolute/path")
set(REL_PATH "../../some/other/relative/path")

# Concatenate your absolute and relative path(s) here.
get_filename_component(COMBINED_PATH ${ABS_PATH}/${REL_PATH} ABSOLUTE)

# Print our merged path to verify.
message(STATUS "COMBINED_PATH: ${COMBINED_PATH}")
```

We can see by the print-out that the new variable `COMBINED_PATH` joins the two paths, resolving any relative-ness.

```
COMBINED_PATH: C:/the/some/other/relative/path
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I am after, as it will not handle two absolute paths. I need to handle both the cases where the prefix is absolute (e.g. `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`), and where it is relative (e.g. `$ORIGIN/..` or `${prefix}` often needed for pkg-config files). And orthogonally, I need to handle both Linux distributions that use relative `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR`, and those that use an absolute one.

Comment: @JanTojnar I updated my response with an additional solution for the *four* cases you described.

Comment: I opened [an issue against CMake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19568), since I feel like omission of such an essential function is a serious bug.

Comment: @JanTojnar I agree that the if-statement solution is cumbersome. But you could generalize it to fit into a utility [`function`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html), and use it anywhere you need it, just like you would `os.path.join()`.